# Unable to install dependencies on legacy Angular code

Tags: angular, npm, package, npm-install, package.json

all.
I got a legacy code in Angular, and I've been stuck on the very start of it cause I can't even install the packages. Seems to be a dependency problem.
[image]

I have tried installing the versions with ~ and ^ and everything else, and everytime I try `npm update` I get this:

[image]

Please help, I can't even begin to work with this. If I use `--legacy-peer-deps` it eventually works, but I've read somewhere in my desperate search that it's not such a good practice.

Here's the `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.6",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "country-calling-code": "^0.0.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "highcharts": "^10.1.0",
    "highcharts-angular": "^3.0.0",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.16",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-intl-tel-input": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-tel-input": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.52.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
```

`npm install` on a legacy code I just got.